# LaTeX3: how to define a variable locally

Tags: latex3, grouping

I am trying to learn the LaTeX3 syntax. One of the questions I have come up with is how to define a variable, i. e. a macro without arguments in TeX parlance, with local scope within a group.

In TeX a `\def`'ed macro is local to the group where it was defined. If `\tl_new:Nn` is the LaTeX3 counterpart of `\def\...{...}`, I expect the variable `\world` to be local to the group as well, but the following code compiles without error:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\group_begin:
  \tl_new:Nn\world{world!}
  %\def\world{world!}
\group_end:
\ExplSyntaxOff

hello \world
\end{document}
```

Why is `\world` visible outside the group?

Comment: Note for future readers: `\tl_new:Nn` has been deprecated for some months (but was not when the question was asked).  Now, use `\tl_new:N` to declare the variable, then later on `\tl_set:Nn` to set the variable locally (or `\tl_gset:Nn` for a global assignment).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`\tl_new:XXXX` is not like `\def` but more like `\newcommand`: it declares a new command to hold content. The content is filled with `\tl_set` and there a local and a global variants exist:
eg. `\tl_gset:Nn` and `\tl_set:Nn`.

Btw: Your example doesn't work for me, I get

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.10 \begin_group
```

with a recent `expl3` from miktex updated 2 days ago.

Comment: I see. Distinction between local and global scope is made during setting the variable's value, not on its declaration. Thanks, this is sufficient as an answer.

Answer (score 14):

To answer the implicit question here (‘why is this the case?’), all of the `\«variable»_new:N` commands create global registers or macros. So for consistency so does `\tl_new:Nn`. We discussed adding also `\«variable»_new_local:N` (see etex.sty for an example of local registers in TeX) but decided that the benefits didn't outweigh the downsides:

For:

- Nice to have local registers (but not necessary)

Against:

- Complicates the syntax and documentation, since we'd then need to explain when/why you'd want to use them.

I liked the idea of writing

```
\group_begin:
  \int_new:N \l_track_loop_int
  ...
  « do stuff with \l_track_loop_int »
  ...
\group_end:
```

but in the end the **big** problem was:

- Local macros behave differently from local registers, which would kill consistency between the `tl` datatype and all others like `int`, `dim`, etc. (And we weren't about to write an allocation system for macros, since efficiency would suffer for very little upside.)

As an example, if the `\«var»_new_local:N` allocators existed:

```
\group_begin:

  \tl_new_local:N \foo
  \tl_gset:Nn \foo {hello}

  \dim_new_local:N \baz
  \dim_gset:Nn \baz {1pt}

\group_end:
```

In such a construction, `\foo` would still be available after the group, whereas `\baz` would not. (Note that globally setting a local variable is perfectly valid.) This was a sufficiently major edge case (in my mind) to definitively decide against the idea.

So the recommended system is to formally declare all variables you intend on using (either lumped together at the beginning of the package or interleaved as you first use them). There's no technical problem, however, with using `\tl_set:Nn` within a group to create a scratch macro if you need.

Comment: Thanks for your explanations! I am beginning to understand. +1

Comment: could you please elaborate a bit on the differences between registers and macros that led to this decision?

Comment: @Philipp Sorry I missed that detail originally. See the update above.

Answer (score 2):

`\tl_new:Nn` expands to `\chk_if_free_cs:N#1\cs_gset_nopar:Npn#1{#2}` and `\cs_gset_nopar:Npn` is `\gdef`. So it gives you a global definition.

Comment: Thanks! So why isn't there a local form as for functions? Are local variables deprecated in LaTeX3? Do I have to resort to `\def` in case I want local variables?

Comment: Why not simply `\tl_set:Nn\world{world!}` ? Btw: I just checked, `\begin_group` and `\end_group` should be this: `\group_begin:` and `\group_end:`

Comment: @ulrike. I see, `\tl_set:Nn` does not require a prior `\tl_new:Nn` and `\tl_set:Nn` is local to its group.